# API Design: Querying a sub-resource

Tags: rest, api-design

We have a resource which could be modeled as a nested object

```
GET /A/
[
  {
    "name": "my_a",
    "B": [
      {"name": "my_b", "address": "0xbeef"}
    ]  
  }
]
```

or a sub resource, like

```
GET /A/my_a/B
[
  {
    "name":"my_b", "address": "0xbeef"
  }
]
```

Our customers want a way to query for objects of type A based on properties of type B, e.g. "get me all the A objects who have B objects with name 'my_b'".

It seems preferable to write the API using the "B as a sub-resource" style of writing because it lends itself to pagination if there are many B object types. Additionally, retrieving B objects can be expensive, so if only some clients are interested in B, it makes sense to required the seperate calls to retrieve subresource B. However, it also seems strange to allow users to query on a sub resource if the sub resource is not returned in the results.

For example, a query feels quite natural when in the form:

```
GET /A?query=B.address[equals]0xbeef
[
  {
    "name": "my_a",
    "B": [
      {"name": "my_b", "address": "0xbeef"}
    ]  
  }
]
```

but less so when the query looks like

```
GET /A?query=B.address[equals]0xbeef
[
  {
    "name": "my_a"
  }
]
```

A compromise I'm considering is using the nested approach but not include the B objects by default. A query parameter can expose B. So,

```
GET /A?query=B.address[equals]0xbeef&include_b=true
[
  {
    "name": "my_a",
    "B": [
      {"name": "my_b", "address": "0xbeef"}
    ]  
  }
]
```

I researched "REST, nested objects, querying" and found examples. Most of these examples included the subresource as a nested object, the `include_b` parameter seems unique to my design.

So, SO, I'm looking for general feedback on this approach, and to see if this is a common problem with a known solution. Curious to hear what comes back.

edit 1: 
Updated the example to show that querying can be on arbitrary properties.

Comment: why not GET /A/B/my_b  ???

Comment: REST doesn't care how your URI looks like, it cares though how the server is informing clients about the URIs and when they should be invoked. As REST is also a generalization of the common Web we use on a daily basis, you can apply the same constructs here also. In HTML you would send a page of selection criterias a user can check within a form element. The form element also specifies the target URI. On translating that approach to your API you should be flexible for future changes.

Comment: @RomanVottner this API is meant to be consumed as JSON. However, I don't think that your comment was disagreeing with my approach, just suggesting a different implementation. Correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: REST is a style which when applied correctly makes clients more robust to changes and grants servers more freedom to change and evolve without breaking clients. These strong benefits don't come for free. As [Fielding](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) stated: almost all of the descriptive effort should be put into defining media types and relation names. `application/json` is probably too generic to convey the meaning of the document and does not define rules and semantics on how to interact with links. Further, it will result in the usage of ...

Comment: [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) where clients expect a certain, generic resource to return specific data. The interaction therefore will be similar to RPC style invocation where the server dictates a certain message format which will couple clients tightly to the service. If you don't need/want the benefits REST provides, simply don't go for it - but, please, don't call it REST then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RomanVottner pointed out, I'm actually not designing a RESTful API. Instead, the API is closer to an RPC translated to use HTTP/JSON. In fact, my team follows the [Google API Design guide](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/) which itself is dictating how to write GRPC APIs which are then (I presume) automatically translated into web endpoints.

So, at the end of the day, I have not had my style question answered, other than to learn that my question wasn't accurate. I will most likely use the solution I purposed in the question.